# Bash run a jar file on text files in a folder

Tags: bash, jar

Theres a jar file that alphabetizes a series of names in .txt file. I have lots of these files in folders. the normal use of the .jar is:

```
java -jar names.jar -o output/alphabetized/ names/names-05-04-20.txt
```

How could you run the jar file on the txt files in a folder?

EDIT: names.jar alphabetizes the contents of the files passed to it, the goal being to alphabetize the contents of the files in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [shell for loop](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/classic_for):

```
for F in names/*.txt; do java -jar names.jar -o output/alphabetized/ "${F}"; done
```

You can see what this is going to do by adding `echo` before `java` to show the command instead of running it:

```
$ for F in names/*.txt; do echo java -jar names.jar -o output/alphabetized/ "${F}"; done
java -jar names.jar -o output/alphabetized/ names/actors.txt
java -jar names.jar -o output/alphabetized/ names/apple-products.txt
java -jar names.jar -o output/alphabetized/ names/fruit.txt
java -jar names.jar -o output/alphabetized/ names/planets.txt
java -jar names.jar -o output/alphabetized/ names/presidents.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

By doing:

```
find . -name *.txt -exec jar -o output/alphabetized {} \;
```

The {} is the name of the file that was found.

Comment: How would the script know which jar file to use?

Comment: You want to put them all in one jar file right? pass that into the script.

Comment: No, the jar file just runs some separate code that would take in the file and alphabetize the context then output it. I want to alphabetize all of the contents of the files in the folder.